# Ctrl+O stops working in Gnome in PopOS (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Recently, I started having a problem with Ctrl+O not working in Vim, running in the terminal in Gnome. I did some investigating and found that it wasn't being received by any application. When I switch to a console session using Ctrl+Alt+F3, the Ctrl+O key combination does work and works in Vim. After switching back to the Gnome session, I'm back to Ctrl+O not working.

While I was trying to diagnose the problem the first time it happened, the problem went away so I figured it was a fluke. Now, the problem is back again.

Note that Ctrl+O seems to be the only key combination that is affected (e.g. Ctrl+U works fine) and it does not make any difference whether I use the right or left Control key.

Any ideas?

---

Additional details: After I restart the system, Ctrl+O works again for some period of time before it stops working again.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked this down to the RingCentral Community app. For some reason, tips that I tried previously to identify what application was capturing a keypress didn't work for me.